# Java draw pixel circle in 2D array

Tags: java, android, arrays, pixel, geometry

I have this code:

```
void drawCircle(int x, int y, int r, int color) {
    double PI = 3.1415926535;
    double i, angle, x1, y1;

    for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 1) {
        angle = i;
        x1 = r * cos(angle * PI / 180);
        y1 = r * sin(angle * PI / 180);

        int ElX = (int) (x + x1);
        int ElY = (int) (y + y1);
        myPixelElements[ElX][ElY].setElementColor(color);
    }
}
```

It almost works but for some reason it draws 2 dots wrong:

[image: Circle it draws]

Comment: Don't use integer division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cos` and `sin` functions produce `double` values from `-1` to `+1`, and when you cast `double` to `int` like this: `int ElX = (int) (x + x1)`, some data will be inevitably lost, because such cast just chops the decimal part away. Instead, I suggest rounding double with `Math.round`, check example below:

```
System.out.println((int) 0.99);            //  0
System.out.println((int) -0.99);           //  0
System.out.println(Math.round(0.99));      //  1
System.out.println(Math.round(-0.99));     // -1
```

Note that `Math.round` returns `long`, so it still must be casted to `int`:

```
int ElX = (int) Math.round(x + x1);
int ElY = (int) Math.round(y + y1);
```

### Output

```
   Before              After

   ******              *****      
  *      *           ***   ***    
 *        *          *       *    
 *        *         **       **   
 *        *         *         *   
 *        **        *         *   
 *        *         *         *   
 *        *         **       **   
  *      *           *       *    
   ******            ***   ***    
      *                *****
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing integer division in these lines:

```
x1 = r * cos(angle * PI / 180);
y1 = r * sin(angle * PI / 180);
```

A couple things are going on here. First, the integer division issue (change `180` to `180.0` to get a quick fix there). Second, you're doing the whole `PI / 180.0` calculation every time through the loop - try pulling it out into its own variable:

```
double degToRadFactor = 3.1415926535 / 180.0

// ...

x1 = r * cos(angle * degToRadFactor)
y1 = r * sin(angle * degToRadFactor)
```

Comment: `public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846` is already `double`, there is no need to fix it.

Comment: `double degToRadFactor = "3.1415926535" / 180.0` will not compile. You are diving a String value

Comment: Whoops! Fixed. Thanks for catching that!